# Quitting a While loop in C++ by entering a blank

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a loop in C++ that am stuck with, I want to end the loop by entering a blank, if a character is entered then the loop goes on. using VS2010

Comment: Voting to close since there are too many details missing.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you have a variable storing a single character, and are wanting to stop the loop when someone enters a blank character (I'm going to presume space).

Just use a if statement and a break clause

```
while (true) {
    // Get character here and put it into myChar variable
    if ( myChar == ' ' )
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

You could also put the check in the while condition if you have nothing else there. Another alternative would be a do-while loop.

Comment: Usually you make the input-statement the loop-condition to handle bad input: `while(std::cin >> myChar)`.

Comment: for some very unknown reason ... it's not working and that's exactly what I did the first time I wrote the code.